# Eliminating duplicate specific rows?

Tags: php, html

Please Help!! I just want to display the Barangay which is talojongon with no other duplicate values
Let's say my current output is:

```
|    Barangay    |    Disease    |
__________________________________
|   Talojongon   |    Cancer     |
|   Talojongon   |    Cancer     |
|   Talojongon   |    Cancer     |
```

and i want to turn this to:

```
|    Barangay    |    Disease    |
__________________________________
|   Talojongon   |    Cancer     |
|                |    Cancer     |
|                |    Cancer     |
```

The receive in the database is for disease and status in the database is the barangay...thank you...Any suggestions is appreciated ..:)

This is my current part of my code

```
        <br>
        <table id="keywords" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th><center>Barangay</th></center>
                    <th><center>Diseases</th></center>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                include 'database.php';
                $pdo = Database::connect();
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM patients WHERE receive="Cancer"';
                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><center>'. $row['status'] . '</center></td>';
                echo '<td><center>'. $row['receive'] . '</center></td>';

                    }
                    Database::disconnect();
                ?>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
```

Comment: `GROUP BY Barangay` *simple enough*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php
    include 'database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM patients WHERE receive="Cancer" order by status';
    $last = '';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
        echo '<tr>';
        if($last == $row['status'])
        {
            echo '<td></td>';
        }
        else
        {
            $last = $row['status'];
            echo '<td><center>'. $row['status'] . '</center></td>';
        }
        echo '<td><center>'. $row['receive'] . '</center></td>';
   }
   Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Comment: @AcayenJesus you're welcome. order by status is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php
            include 'database.php';
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM patients WHERE receive="Cancer"';
            $counter=0;
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row){
            $counter++;
            echo '<tr>';
            if($counter==1){
            echo '<td><center>Cancer</center></td>';
            }else{
            echo '<td><center></center></td>';
            }
            echo '<td><center>'. $row['receive'] . '</center></td>';

                }
                Database::disconnect();
            ?>
```

Simply echo the status just in the first row...

Comment: @AcayenJesus you welcome. may also have a look at barmers answer. There are some good improvements to your code...

Comment: @AcayenJesus by the way, you cannot mark multiple answers, its best style to upvote all and mark the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

Save the last value of `$row['status']` in a variable. If it's the same leave it blank in the output.

```
$last_status = null;
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $status = $row['status'] == $last_status ? '' : $row['status'];
    echo '<td style="text-align: center;">' . $status . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="text-align: center;">' . $row['receive'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $last_status = $row['status'];
}
```

Also, you shouldn't use the obsolete `<center>` tag, use CSS. And `</tr>` should be inside the loop, not at the end.

You probably should also use `ORDER BY status` in the query, so that all the rows with the same status are together.